# is there a way to write stream analytics output to Azure documentdb

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-stream-analytics

I am developing an application . I am pushing data to event hub .From event hub i need to use stream analytics and push data to DOcumentdb for analytics purpose. Could any one please guide me to push data from stream analytics to documentdb. I could see output to SQL Database,Blob storage,Event Hub,Power BI preview,Table storage, Service Bus Queue, Service Bus Topic only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** this feature is now implemented, and DocumentDB can be used as a sink for Stream Analytics: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/streamanalytics/archive/2015/09/29/stream-analytics-updates-for-the-azure-iot-suite.aspx

Yes this effort has already been started while ago as per the [feedback forum](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/270577-azure-stream-analytics/suggestions/7114244-can-we-add-an-output-to-documentdb) and it should be publicly available soon. Please share more feedback about your  scenario over there and maybe why Azure Table or SQL output are not satisfying it.

thanks!

Comment: thanks , i could see the Support for DocumentDB support in stream analytics now